# Tikz-UML sequence diagram: How to make a lifeline thick (in tikz umlsdiag)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-uml

How can I make the lifelines more sharply and better visible? If I print the diagram it´s not good visible.
An other possibility could be if I change the color of all lines to black. But I think it´s default.
All ideas and approaches are welcome.

That´s my tex-file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn,oneside, parskip=full]{article}
\usepackage[left=4cm,top=2cm,right=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{document}
Sequencediagram is shown in figure 1.
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{seq_workflow.tikz}}
\caption[sequencediagram]{sequencediagram}
\vspace{-0.2cm}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And this is my diagram-file:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
    \umlactor[no ddots, x=0, y=0, scale=0.5, fill={white}]{user}
    \umlbasicobject[x=3, fill={green}]{object1}
    \umlobject[x=6, no ddots, fill={green}]{object2}
    \umlbasicobject[x=11, fill={green}]{object3}
    \umlbasicobject[x=17, fill={green}]{object4}
    \umlactor[no ddots, x=19, y=0, scale=0.5, fill={white}]{user2}
    \begin{umlcall}[dt=8, op=\shortstack{do something}, type=synchron, return=ready]{user}{object1}
    \begin{umlcall}[dt=4, op=\shortstack{message}, type=synchron, return=received, padding=3]{object1}{object4}
    \end{umlcall}
    \begin{umlcall}[op=\shortstack{message}, type=synchron, return=received, padding=3]{object1}{object2}
    \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlcall}
    \begin{umlcall}[op=new entry, type=asynchron]{object2}{object2}
    \end{umlcall}
    \begin{umlcall}[dt=30, op=request, type=synchron, return=entry, padding=3]{user2}{object3}          
    \begin{umlcall}[dt=4, op=request, type=synchron, return=response]{object3}{object2}
    \begin{umlcall}[dt=4, op=request, type=asynchron]{object2}{object2}
    \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlcall}
    \umlsdnode[dt=23]{user}
    \umlsdnode[dt=23]{object1}
    \umlsdnode[dt=3]{object2}
    \umlsdnode[dt=32]{object4}
\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If you print *which diagram*? To be able to help you with a problem, we have to know the problem. To do so, we need to know in detail, what you are doing. This means you always should show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) beginning with `\documentclass` including all *needed* packages and preamble code and showing a *minimal* body from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: You're loading `tikzscale` but not using it, so your lines are scaled, as well as fonts. If your picture is too large, this will makes the lines very thin.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Now I can print a better version of my diagram. I´ve changed line 3854 in tikz-uml.sty (I add a parameter: very thick)
The old block:

```
{%
  % draw lifelines of each object
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{lifelines}%
  \foreach \id in \tikzumlIdList {%
  \draw (\csname tikzumlLastChild@\id \endcsname)+(0,-2.5ex) node[inner sep=0, name=end-\id] {};%
  \draw[dotted] (\id) -- (end-\id);%
  }%
  \end{pgfonlayer}%
  \end{scope}%
}%
```

[image]

The changed block:

```
{%
  % draw lifelines of each object
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{lifelines}%
  \foreach \id in \tikzumlIdList {%
  \draw (\csname tikzumlLastChild@\id \endcsname)+(0,-2.5ex) node[inner sep=0, name=end-\id] {};%
  \draw[very thick, dotted] (\id) -- (end-\id);%
  }%
  \end{pgfonlayer}%
  \end{scope}%
}%
```

[image]

@cfr: If I load the picture without it, latex can not read the tikz-file with \includegraphics. The picture is after printing a little bit small but I have to use A4 as paper size. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Oh please do not change a file that you do not own. You are only allowed to use it.